# Why doesn't igraph's add_vertices() work with a set of strings?

Tags: python, igraph

This is no doubt due to my lack of knowledge of Python ... but why does this not work with igraph?

```
import igraph
g=igraph.Graph()
verts = {'1','2','3'}
g.add_vertices(verts)
for v in g.vs:
    print v
```

Output:

```
igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x106347908>,0,{'name': set(['1', '3', '2'])})
igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x106347908>,1,{'name': set(['1', '3', '2'])})
igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x106347908>,2,{'name': set(['1', '3', '2'])})
```

I would have expected the following output (which I get with `add_vertices(list(verts))`):

```
igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x106347af8>,0,{'name': '1'})
igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x106347af8>,1,{'name': '3'})
igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x106347af8>,2,{'name': '2'})
```

The documentation on [`add_vertices`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#add_vertices) says,

> `add_vectirces(n)`  `n` - the number of vertices to be added, or the name of a single vertex to be added, or an iterable of strings, each corresponding to the name of a vertex to be added. Names will be assigned to the name vertex attribute.

I thought `verts` was a valid iterable of strings.  Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

From the igraph [source](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-pysrc.html#Graph.add_vertices):

```
def add_vertices(self, n): 
     if isinstance(n, basestring):
          # some code
     elif hasattr(n, "__iter__"): 
          m = self.vcount() 
          if not hasattr(n, "__len__"): 
               names = list(n) 
          else: 
               names = n 
          result = GraphBase.add_vertices(self, len(names)) 
          self.vs[m:]["name"] = names # assignment is done here
          return result
```

It would seem reasonable to assign the `name` atribute of each vertex in that slice of vertex sequence to the values in `names` -- if this was done in pure Python, it would pass simply as *unpacking* -- but the `GraphBase` which the `Graph` class subclasses was written in c.

So that behavior can only be described by the outcome. If you pass an unordered `iterable` (`set` and `dict`), each attribute of the vertex sequence takes the `iterable` itself as value, but if you pass an ordered iterable (say `tuple` or `list`), the values are *unpacked* (not in the python sense) and assigned to that slice of `vs`.

You can confirm this by repeating your code snippet on:

```
verts = ('1','2','3') # ordered
```

and

```
verts = {'1': 'one' ,'2': 'two', '3': 'three'} # unordered
```

But `frozensets`?

Well `frozensets` are also not subscriptable, so the C code would simply repeat the same behavior as with a `set`.

> I thought `verts` was a valid iterable of strings

But not valid for indexing in Python. I guess the documentation needs a face lift.